# Comparing pre and post responses of anonymous survey data?

Tags: repeated-measures, survey, likert, pre-post-comparison

We have a survey with a pre and post question on student interest toward science (likert scale -" I am interested in science").   The survey was conducted in a large district and we have 1200 responses pre and 900 responses post.

Because of IRB and to encourage particicipation, we have no identifiers (both surveys were anonymous) so the responses cannot be matched.  Is there any valid statistical comparison of the means?